# Does anybody have gdb pretty-printer code for an fd_set on linux?

Tags: python, c, linux, network-programming, gdb

Modern versions of gdb allow integration of python code to "pretty print" complex data structures.  There are some great pretty printer implementations for C++'s STL classes as well as some of the more common `boost.org` types.

In network programming, one commonly encounters `select`/`poll` calls.  While `poll()` uses an array of data structures, `select()` uses `fd_set`.

Has anyone run across a pretty printer implementation for `fd_set`, preferably portable, but even platform-specific would be okay.  Ideally, it'd be linux/x86, but I'd take anything and hope to be able to adapt.

Comment: Unfortunately, fd_set's contents are implementation dependent, so a portable solution would need access to C header files, making a portable, pure Python solution unlikely.

Comment: I know fd_sets can be implementation-dependent.  AFAIK there are python tools that allow python code to interact with C data structures (similar to the facility in Perl that does the same), but I haven't gone down that road yet.  As I pointed out, I'm happy with an existing non-portable solution even if it's not for my desired platform because it would at least be a starting point.

Comment: I'm making a stab at it.  The issue isn't so much interaction with the data structures, but that byte order and the names of structure elements aren't determined.  In fact, fd_set is a typedef for an anonymous structure for most Linuxes, so even determining that a given struct is an fd_set is heuristic.  Will add an answer once I have a functioning hack of it.

Comment: Sweet!  While the structure themselves aren't portable, the type and related macros are pretty consistent.  Maybe I should look into writing C code that compiles into a .so with a python front-end...to portably decode an fd_set.  With regard to being able to determine that something is an fd_set, it would be reasonable to me to have to cast.

Answer (score 4):

Alrighty, here's something I wrote which seems to work for me under Linux.  Let me know if it works for you:

**anonprint.py**

```
import gdb

class fd_set_printer:
  """
  Prints an fd_set, which is normally an opaque
  array of ints, each bit representing one file descriptor
  """

  def __init__(self, val, val_array):
    self.val = val
    self.val_array = val_array

  @staticmethod
  def find_set_bits(bit_array):
    """
    Finds set bits in a long bit list.
    Expects a gdb.Value which contains a C array,
      such as int[10], and treats it as a bitlist
      of int_size * 10 bits long.  Returns an array of
      bit positions, starting with 0, for which the bits
      are on.
    e.g. for int foo[] = [1, 6], it will return [ 0, 33, 34 ]
    The array should be given as a gdb.Value
    """
    set_bits = []
    bits_length = bit_array[0].type.sizeof * 8
    current_bit = 0

    # Can not use 'for current_byte in gdb.Value:' even if
    #  gdb.Value.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_ARRAY
    # So iteration happens this ugly C-style way
    for current_byte_pos in xrange(*bit_array.type.range()):
      current_byte = bit_array[current_byte_pos]
      for bit in xrange(0, bits_length):
        bit_mask = 1 << bit
        if bit_mask & current_byte == bit_mask:
          set_bits.append(current_bit)
        current_bit += 1

    return set_bits

  def to_string(self):
    fd_list = self.find_set_bits(self.val_array)
    if len(fd_list) == 0:
      output = "Empty file descriptor set."
    else:
      output = "File descriptor set: "
      output += ', '.join(map(str, fd_list))
    return output


def anon_struct_lookup_function(val):
  """
  Checks if the given value looks like an fd_set.
  If it does, delegates printing to the printer
  """
  lookup_tag = val.type.tag
  if lookup_tag == None:
    return None
  if lookup_tag != "<anonymous struct>":
    return None

  fields = val.type.fields()
  val_array = None

  if len(fields) == 1 and fields[0].name == 'fds_bits':
    val_array = val['fds_bits']
  elif len(fields) == 1 and fields[0].name == '__fds_bits':
    val_array = val['__fds_bits']

  if not val_array is None:
    return fd_set_printer(val, val_array)

  return None


def add_fd_set_printer(obj = gdb):
  "Adds the fd_set pretty printer to the given object"
  obj.pretty_printers.append(anon_struct_lookup_function)
```

And then make your `~/.gdbinit`:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/anonprint_py_directory_here')
from anonprint import add_fd_set_printer
add_fd_set_printer()
end
```

This is the first time I tried to interact with gdb internals via Python, so commentary and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I will try it out in the next couple of days, hopefully.  Thanks!

Comment: Have not forgotten...just have been diverted on other issues.  It's not off the radar, though.